# Is there a way to put Chosen jQuery Plugin always to front?

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, jquery-chosen, jquery-layout

I'm trying to use Chosen plugin with some other plugins like jQuery Layout and jqgrid

Without Chosen my select box look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8qQv.png

And with Chosen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlSMz.png

it's overlapped by jQuery Layout.

Is there a way to put Chosen always to front?

I played around with different CSS settings of both plugins, but to no avail..
Help please to figure out what to do.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-layout-center"></div>
<div class="ui-layout-north">
    <div style="width: 250px; position:relative; z-index:99999">
        <select id="picker" style="width: 250px">
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</div>
<div class="ui-layout-south"></div>
<div class="ui-layout-east"></div>
<div class="ui-layout-west"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#picker').chosen();
$('body').layout(
    { applyDefaultStyles: true }
);
```

Link to JSFiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrd3w/2/)

Comment: try to give `position:relative; z-index:100` to the parent div of your dropdown list

Comment: @Era Post it in Answers, i will definitely Vote Up..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nested div with a z-index will never be higher than an element outside of the parent. [This](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) article explains it well. what you could do is move the nested div outside and toggle the visibility when `.ui-layout-toggler-north` is clicked. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrd3w/5/)

```
$('.ui-layout-toggler-north').click(function(){
    $('#chosen_select').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Note: I put a select element in the .ui-layout-north div as a placholder for the actual "chosen select" element.

Answer (score 8):

Try to give: `position:relative; z-index:100` to the parent div of your dropdown list. or provide a fiddle to get better answer.

Comment: Yes pls provide a fiddle for better understanding.

Comment: Unfortunately your decision doesn't work.. Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yrd3w/2/

Comment: I spent days trying to fix it, until I found you! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this css style.

```
position: fixed; 
_position: absolute; 
z-index: 99; 
left: 0; 
top: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
_height: expression(document.body.offsetHeight + "px");
```

This help you on your problem. ^ ^

Comment: Its not working. Here is fiddle jsfiddle.net/yrd3w/2

Comment: I test your example.. I see what is your problem. You can't put it in front because of the different <DIV> you use. Try also MODAL or auto re-size the height and width on you perspective <div> you to see the dropdown.